# Segmentation fault (core dumped) runtime error

Tags: c, linux, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int split;
    pid_t childpid;

    char *x = argv[1];
        
    int status;
    char splitindex_string[40];
    split = atoi(x);    
    printf("%d\n" ,split );
    
    int indexfile_split = 320000/split;

    snprintf(splitindex_string,40, "%d", indexfile_split);
    
    childpid = fork();

    if(childpid==0){
        execlp("/bin/split", "split", "l", splitindex_string, "-a", "1" ,"-d", "input.txt", "output",  NULL);
        return 0;
    }

    else{
        int status;
        wait(&status);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

i have this c code, but when i run the output i keep getting this weird segmentation fault (core dumped) error. the code compiles fine, the error only appears after i run the binary. from what I read online im probably accessing invalid memory. Ive been staring at this for hours now. help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: is this c or c++? (It is not portable c++ afaik)

Comment: its c code not c++ (i apologize for the inappropriate tag )

Comment: On Linux, you can use gdb to retrieve a backtrace: `gdb <binary> core`, and then `bt`.

Comment: `l` is not an option to `split`, use `-l` instead.

Comment: yeah youre correct i fixed it but it didnt help me. i got the same runtime error

Comment: What input do you provide? Where does it crash if you run it in a debugger like GDB?

Comment: Before using CLI arguments, you should check number of parameters.

Comment: You have `char *x = argv[1];` but failed to check `argc`. It's *de rigueur*.

Comment: it worked, the code itself isn't the problem. i was providing the wrong input.

Comment: Did you remember to pass a command-line argument when running it?  There's no check in the code, so instead of giving an appropriate error message, your program will segment fault if no argument is provided (it's a bug).

Comment: yeah, i placed a checker for the command line argument and realized i was providing invalid input. thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the missed check over input. If you don't provide argument to the executable it crash, and give you the error you say.

**I suggest you to introduce a check over the argument provided, before accessing them.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if your program is invoked correctly, for example like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc < 2)
    {
       printf("You didn't provide enough arguments\n");
       return 1;
    }

    int split;
    pid_t childpid;
    ...
```

If `argc <2`  then `argv[1]` doesn't exist and dereferencing it will result in undefined behaviour.